# Ordering list by 3 numbers

Tags: c#, list

I have a List<> with objects, that hold multiple fields, which are mostly numbers. I want to sort this list, by 3 of those numbers. I've tried this:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Val3).ThenBy(x => x.Val2)
                                .ThenBy(x => x.Val1).ToList();
```

which works fine, but only for the first two order/thenbys. The third one seems to not get run at all. I can sort for any combination of two of those values just fine, but the third on is always ignored.

I haven't tried the non LINQ approach yet, because I'm simply curious where the problem here is. Can't you sort for 3 values? What's the problem here? In case this matters in any way, 3 is a ushort, while 2 and 1 are uints.

Comment: I think it's because ThenBy is deferred execution till you enumerate but not 100% sure:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx

Comment: Maybe a longshot, but are you sure you need that final ToList()?

Comment: Maybe you need to post the creation of your list and the class that's used to make up the list. I just tried it and it works for me (including the uint and ushort parts). I'd post my code to show you, but it's not really an answer. It just works.

Comment: Actually, I posted an answer. Maybe you can compare your code to mine? If mine is different than yours, perhaps I can change it to help you get it working.

Comment: @Mars is it actually a list? Or something IList or IQuerable?

Comment: I agree with @BobHorn, multiple `ThenBy`s just works. Please include your class definition and sample data that reproduces this issue.

Comment: @mars have you resolved the issue? Did my code help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are any better solutions. If I were you, I would weight the value2 by multiply a big value. Just like:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Val3).ThenBy(x => x.Val2 * 10000 + x.Val1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this hack:

```
 list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Val2).OrderBy(x => x.Val3).ThenBy(x => x.Val1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) says

> "This design enables you to specify multiple sort criteria by applying
>   any number of ThenBy or ThenByDescending methods."

So what you give as example code should work. In the absence of a specified comparator ThenBy uses the [Default comparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx). Are you sure that val1 is sortable using the default comparator?

---

EDIT: Doh! just saw "I can sort for any combination of two of those values just fine, but the third on is always ignored." so it seems that val1 is sortable by the default comparator.

The documentation and the answer from @Bob Horn suggests that your example should work. Can you add more details of the objects you're ordering?

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It doesn't. Which I realised after answering and edited to demonstrate that it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: this should be added as a comment, since it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem because it just works. However, perhaps you can compare your code to this and see how it differs?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Val1 { get; set; }
    public uint Val2 { get; set; }
    public ushort Val3 { get; set; }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OrderFoos();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void OrderFoos()
    {
        List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
        list.Add(new Foo() { Name = "2nd", Val1 = 2, Val2 = 1, Val3 = 1 });
        list.Add(new Foo() { Name = "1st", Val1 = 1, Val2 = 1, Val3 = 1 });
        list.Add(new Foo() { Name = "3rd", Val1 = 1, Val2 = 2, Val3 = 1 });
        list.Add(new Foo() { Name = "4th", Val1 = 2, Val2 = 1, Val3 = 2 });
        list.Add(new Foo() { Name = "6th", Val1 = 4, Val2 = 1, Val3 = 3 });
        list.Add(new Foo() { Name = "5th", Val1 = 3, Val2 = 1, Val3 = 3 });            

        list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Val3).ThenBy(x => x.Val2).ThenBy(x => x.Val1).ToList();

        list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
    }
```

[image]